# How to parse numbers from different locale formats?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localization, numbers

Is there an already existing solution that can parse all the numbers below?

```
"300.00"
"2.300,00"
"2,300.00"
```

Comment: While the supplied cases are trivial to normalize, what about `2.300` and `2,300`? What about `2'300.0` and `1,02,300`? (If such numbers/cases are outside the scope of this question then it should be explicitly stated as such.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the [`money`](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money) gem:

`$ gem install money`

Then you can do:

```ruby
require 'money'

test1 = Money.parse("300.00")
test2 = Money.parse("2.300,00")
test3 = Money.parse("2,300.00")

test1.currency # #<Money::Currency id: usd, priority: 1, symbol_first: true, thousands_separator: ,, html_entity: $, decimal_mark: ., name: United States Dollar, symbol: $, subunit_to_unit: 100, iso_code: USD, iso_numeric: 840, subunit: Cent>
test1.amount # 300.0
test1.dollars # 300.0
test1.cents # 30000
test1.currency_as_string # USD
test1.separator # .
test1.thousands_separator # ,
test1.delimiter # ,
```

**EDIT:** the old `money` gem has split into two parts: `money` and `monetize`. The new `money` class only handles creating, manipulating and converting currencies between `money` objects.

To parse objects (including strings) into `money` objects, **you should use the [`monetize`](https://github.com/RubyMoney/monetize) gem** instead:

```
$ gem install monetize

Monetize.parse("USD 100")
Monetize.parse("£100")
Monetize.parse_collection("€80, $100")
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out: "he old money gem has split into two parts: money and monetize"